# Browser logout on back button

Tags: java, session, jsf

I'm currently researching the best method of solving an issue I'm having and was wondering if you could help.

I have a user profile section in my website that I want to make a bit more secure.

I have an issue where when a user logs in, if they click the back button it takes them back to the login page but they're still logged in. How can I have it log the user out and take them to the logout page?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried setting the cache control to no cache? i.e. response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");

Comment: If I'm right, you save the User data in session. When you press the back button, the session will have the User data in it, so that's basic behavior. The problem would be if the user selects log out, press the back button and all his/her data is still on the web.

Comment: How are they being logged in or out? I use php for this and I would just do something like if the page I am at is the login page, automatically do the logout action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are trying to do the right thing. Users know and use the back button, and it is helpful to them if that button takes them back to what they were doing beforehand. Having it automatically log users out breaks some basic assumptions about how web applications work, and I don't recommend that you do this.

Also, the problem is worse than you think it is. You mentioned users who use the back button, but what about users who use right-click-open-in-new-tab to open several tabs viewing your application, then switch back and forth between the tabs?

That being said, here is a way you can achieve what you want. You need to track most-recently-viewed-page in the user's session on the server. Each time you get a new request, compare against the cached value in the session and if it's not a page that could have navigated here, clear out the session and display the login page. Another way the same thing is achieved is to generate a key as each page is displayed (a large random number will do) which is passed on the subsequent request, and when any page is requested and it doesn't have the most recent key then clear the session and display the login page.